# PWA Push API vs Android Push Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push

today i have a question about:

**Progressive Web Apps** and the **Push API** vs native **Android Applications** and their **Push Notification** counter part. I want to know how both approaches work.

To my understanding the **service worker** of the PWA (Progressive Web App) using the **Push API** receives their **push message** from a **push service**, whichs is a system used by the **application server**.
The **service worker** can then display a **notification** on the device.

How does a native android application do this?

Maybe like this:
The **android application** uses the **FirebaseMessaging API** to receive their **push message** from the **firebase service** used by the **application server**. 
The **application** can then display a **notification** on the device. Even different kind of notifications (status bar notification, heads-up notification, lock screen notifications, app icon badge notifications)

Do both, pwa and the native apps use **FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)** ? 
Where are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet used FCM in a PWA but would recommend it based on what I have read. Especially the fact that FCM supports Topic-Based message subscriptions such as weather-forecasts, sports-reports, news-headlines etc.

W3C/IETF force your application to keep track of ***ALL*** mapping of individual user-subscriptions. That is, ***NO*** message broadcast capability :-(